# Stopping #s4-titlerow inline styling SP2010

Tags: 2010, master-page, branding

I have a Masterpage which has custom CSS with some padding on the `#s4-bodyContainer` on some pages my `#s4-titlerow` gets an inline style and causes horizontal scrolling.

I don't want this inline style to happen and can't figure out how to stop it, or correct it instantly in the event it does happen.

Comment: Did you try to override some style attribute on the fly to see what works, using Firefox + Firebug perhaps?   Try for example by adding "overflow:hidden" to #s4-titlerow.

Comment: overflow:hidden would work but obviously anything overflowed by SharePoint would then also be hidden.  My only options at this point are either doing a CSS !important (which I am trying to avoid) or something via Javascript.  My preference is to use javascript to remove or best yet stop SharePoint from doing it.

Answer (score 1):

If it is an inline style via the Style attribute then the only way that you can change that is to use Javascript to change it, otherwise, it will override all other styles coming in from the CSS.  jQuery makes this amazingly simple to do.

Comment: My issue is figuring out the timing to remove the style attribute. My attempt to remove the style attribute is firing before the SharePoint javascript which sets it.

Comment: Using .ready fires before the SharePoint javascript which sets the style.

Comment: A clumsy option would be to use SetTimeout to keep checking the Style attribute and then change it once the other javascript has set it